# Find a basis and the dimension of the vector space, $V = \left\{\begin{pmatrix}{z}\\{w}\end{pmatrix}\in\Bbb{C}^2:z-4w=0\right\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification, vectors

I am trying to find a basis for vector space $V$ as well as the vector space's dimension. Below is my working so far:

$$z=4w\Longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}{z}\\{w}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}{4w}\\{w}\end{pmatrix}\in\Bbb{C}^2\\$$

Now, in order for $V$ to be a spanning set of $\Bbb{C}^2$ the dimension of the vector space must be 2.

This is as far as I have got. I believe that $\text{Dim}(V)=1$ and $\mathcal{B}=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}{4w}\\{w}\end{pmatrix}\right\}$, though I am unsure how to continue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Set a specific value for $w$, say $w=1$, to obtain a basis.

Comment: Note that $(4w,w)=w(4,1)$. Since $w$ is independent this describes the entire space.